# Use tornado as websocket is too slow to process big file, can everybody help me to refine the performance

Tags: html, performance, websocket, tornado

I used tornado to receive file from client and found the process was too slow. I added log in tornado code, and found that the fllowing codes spent too long time on websocket.py-->WebSocketProtocol13-->_apply_mask function.

The code is:
for i in xrange(len(data)):
unmasked[i] = unmasked[i] ^ mask[i % 4]

Can everybody give me some idea about how to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to optimize this further in pure python, but see this pull request for a C-based speedup: https://github.com/facebook/tornado/pull/579

Comment: Thanks very much. I rewrite this funtion in c and optimize the spending time from 3-4s to 1s for processing 5MB data. I will try https://github.com/facebook/tornado/pull/579 too